# jsPDF: print a pdf created directly to the printer device

Tags: javascript, dom-events, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

In my "classic ASP" code I can dynamically create a PDF using jsPDF (JavaScript PDF Creator) Library:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var name = "Smith, John"
doc.setFontType("normal");
doc.setFontSize(12);
doc.text(20,20,'Name: '+ name);
doc.save("filename.pdf");    
doc.autoPrint();
```

Now if I put this code in my ASP page the .PDF will saved but not printed.

Using the online snippet (like https://veryutils.com/demo/jspdf/), my script works, but works only choosing AUTOPRINT in the combobox.
This mean that some JS or library is added choosing AUTOPRINT.

Starting from a new page, which .JS I have to "connect" to allow `.autoprint` method?

Comment: Is the *asp-classic* relevant here? Maybe [this](https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-autoprint.html) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes thanks. I had already found that manual. The problem is that it doesn't work "locally", so that probably needs a particular .js linked (tag <script>) to work.

Comment: https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/modules_autoprint.js.html

Comment: Did you add this one?

Comment: This row must be added to the code?
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server/src/modules/autoprint.js"></script>

Still not works

Comment: If you go on "online snippet" website and you add the row
<code>
doc.autoPrint();
</code>
you can see that the row not works.

It works only choosing AUTOPRINT in the combobox.
This mean that "something" must be added (somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this option by playing with the keys from the [jspDF documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html#output)

This option helped me:

```
doc.autoPrint();
doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

Comment: autoPrint not work without a correct package (modules/autoprint.js)
Can you share your <LINK> tags?

Comment: Any "full" example?